# How remove class step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list items:

```
<ul>
    <li> 1</li>
    <li> 2</li>
    <li> 3</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 4</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 5</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 6</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 7</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 8</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 9</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 10</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 11</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 12</li>
</ul>

<div id="btn">click btn</div>

$(function () {
  $('#btn').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); //stops the document click action
    $('ul li.item').removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

This jQuery code remove all class "*hidden*", but how to remove a class first from the first three, then the next three and etc... ?

It should look like this:

**click btn**

```
<ul>
    <li> 1</li>
    <li> 2</li>
    <li> 3</li>
    <li class="item "> 4</li>
    <li class="item "> 5</li>
    <li class="item "> 6</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 7</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 8</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 9</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 10</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 11</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 12</li>
</ul>
```

and **click btn**

```
<ul>
    <li> 1</li>
    <li> 2</li>
    <li> 3</li>
    <li class="item "> 4</li>
    <li class="item "> 5</li>
    <li class="item "> 6</li>
    <li class="item "> 7</li>
    <li class="item "> 8</li>
    <li class="item "> 9</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 10</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 11</li>
    <li class="item hidden"> 12</li>
</ul>
```

and etc...

https://jsfiddle.net/ep8dk9o5/

Comment: [`.slice(0, 3)`](//api.jquery.com/slice/). Also, familiarize yourself with the other [traversing methods](//api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+filter+first+three+elements) of [How to select first N elements with jquery?](/q/6730512/4642212).

Comment: Based on the duplicate you end up with something like this: `$('ul li.item.hidden:lt(3)').removeClass('hidden');`

Comment: You can use eq to select the item at the index you need. 
like this `$('ul li').eq(0).removeClass('theclass')` and you make it one by one, or you can use css selector and remove the three at once:
`$('ul li:nth-of-type(1), ul li:nth-of-type(2), ul li:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass('theclass')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the button is clicked, just slice up the items which has hidden class as done below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); //stops the document click action
    $('ul li.item.hidden').slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> 1</li>
  <li> 2</li>
  <li> 3</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 4</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 5</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 6</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 7</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 8</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 9</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 10</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 11</li>
  <li class="item hidden"> 12</li>
</ul>

<div id="btn">click btn</div>
```

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqpde2x9/) for this answer